# rsync -option explaination?

Tags: backup, rsync, remote-backup, cwrsync

I've seen the switches below on an rsync script and I just wondered if someone could break them down for me...

```
rsync --chmod=ugo=rwX
```

ugo?
rwX (read-write-Execute - why the capitalisation on Execute?)

```
--chmod=CHMOD           affect file and/or directory permissions
```

Also what is "don't cross filesystem boundaries" for the -x option?

```
-x, --one-file-system   don't cross filesystem boundaries
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the syntax of `chmod` and has nothing to do with rsync options: Set user (`u`), group (`g`) and other (`o`) access to read (`r`), write (`w`), and if for the existing file or directory already set, then add execute (`X`) rights.

As you can [mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29) different file systems, you could limit rsync to stay on one file system, for this is the `-x` option.

Comment: Actually capital X in chmod means to apply execute if it is a directory or already has execute permission. Meaning that execute will always be set on directories.